# Why do all SSL subdomains direct to the same IP

Tags: ssl, proxy, apache2, virtualhost, reverse-proxy

I have my apache server set up to act as a reverse proxy for two services. One runs on `192.168.1.50:5000` an the other runs on `192.168.1.121:8989`.

I want `https://apple.example.com` to go to `192.168.1.50:5000` and `https://orange.example.com` to go to `192.168.1.121:8989`.

`apple.example.com` works as expected, but for some reason, when I have both sites enabled, whenever I try to load `orange.example.com` it instead loads `apple` and the address Chrome is `https://apple.example.com`. If I disable the `apple` vhost, `orange` works as expected

Here are my two virtual hosts:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyRequests Off
    ServerName apple.example.com
    ServerAlias www.apple.example.com
    ProxyPass / http://192.168.1.50:5000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.1.50:5000/    

    <Location />
        SSLRequireSSL
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Location>

    SSLEngine On
    SSLProxyEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.key
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName apple.example.com
    ServerAlias www.apple.example.com
    Redirect permanent / https://apple.example.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyRequests Off
    ServerName orange.example.com
    ServerAlias www.orange.example.com
    ProxyPass / http://192.168.1.121:8989/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.1.121:8989/   

    <Location />
        SSLRequireSSL
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Location>

    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.key
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName orange.example.com
    ServerAlias www.orange.example.com
    Redirect permanent / https://orange.example.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

After about 2 hours of trying to figure this out, I realized that because my redirect was permanent, it was being cached in Chrome. At some point, my browser must have stored a permanent redirect from `orange` to `apple`. I figured this out when I realized that going to `https://orange.example.com` worked but `http://apple.example.com` would redirect to `apple`. After clearing my browser cache, it worked perfectly. Very frustrating.